# A Logic Puzzle—One of These Things Doesn’t Quite Fit

Tags: symbols

Here’s a puzzle I just thought of this morning. Good luck!

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect it is the Symbol

> F
>  All other symbols can be drawn in one stroke, similar to the famous riddle "the house of Nikolaus"